# Undefined function or variable 'mmreader'

Tags: matlab

I try to use matlab 2016a to read avi videos, however, I get the following problems:

undefined funciton or variable 'mmreader';
The code is as following:

```
clc;
clear;
%% this to read avi by using mmread to get every frame
video = mmreader('D:\My Documents\MATLAB\My\fire.avi');
nFrames = video.NumberOfFrames;
H = video.Height;
W = video.Width;
Rate = video.FrameRate;
% Preallocate movie structure.
mov(1:nFrames) = struct('cdata',zeros(H,W,3,'uint8'),'colormap',[]);


%read one frame every time
for i = 1:nFrames
mov(i).cdata = read(video,i);
P = mov(i).cdata;
 disp('current frame number：'),disp(i);
 imshow(P),title('original picture');


%     P2=rgb2gray(P);

end
```

Why? Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will more likely get help if you post both code and error message in English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `mmreader` was deprecated in version R2010b, removed in version R2014a, and removed from the documentation altogether in version R2015b. It was replaced by the [`VideoReader`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.html) function, so use that in its place.

Comment: error use VideoReader/init (line 607) MATLAB paths do not include pointed file name. Error VideoReader (line 172) obj.init(fileName);

Error AvitoPic (line 4)
    video = VideoReader('D:\My Documents\MATLAB\My\fire.avi');

Comment: @Small_Bird: I think there's a language barrier here, but this looks like a problem with your file path. Either the file doesn't exist on that path, or MATLAB can't interpret the characters used for the folder name. Try renaming the folder as something with standard ASCII characters.

Comment: I am sorry, but not the reason. I change the path to 'E:\ch02_20170323193606.avi', however, the result remains the same.

Comment: @Small_Bird: Do you get a true result (i.e. logical 1) from the following?: `exist('E:\ch02_20170323193606.avi', 'file') == 2` If not, your file isn't being detected. If so, I don't know what the issue could be.

Comment: Thanks, the problem has been solved. You are right, the path is wrong!